# Adding JQuery.com to asp.NET adds a Header saying Loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I added the html below to my MasterPage in Webforms and now at the bottom of the page, I get a H1 Header at the bottom of the pages now saying LOADING .  Hows that happening?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there any js\html error in browser developer console?

Comment: Debugging in Firefox didn't seem to show anything untoward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the .css file to the page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```